# How could I do SELECT using LIKE effective?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying execute a query using LIKE. I'm using `LIKE or LIKE`, because I need the SELECT return a value or other, it's works. The problem is I need this return by `cidade`, cidade is a table in my data base.

I'm trying this.

```
public function getLocalByNomeOrTipo($value, $idCidade){
        $find = "%".$value."%";
        $stm = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM locais t1
                                        INNER JOIN cidade t2 ON (t1.cidade_id = t2.id)
                                        INNER JOIN tipo_local t3 ON (t1.tipo_local_id = t3.id)
                                        WHERE (t1.cidade_id = ?) AND (status = 1) AND (t1.nome LIKE ? OR t3.tipo LIKE ?)
                                        ORDER BY t1.nome");
        $stm->bindParam(1, $idCidade);
        $stm->bindParam(2, $find);
        $stm->bindParam(3, $find);
        $stm->execute();
        $lista = $stm->fetchAll();

        return $lista;
    }
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?  Perhaps you should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need that issue return only values of `t1.cidade_id = 1` for example, but does not works and always return all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

```
public function getLocalByNomeOrTipo($value, $idCidade){
        $find = "%".$value."%";
        $stm = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM locais t1
                                        INNER JOIN cidade t2 ON (t1.cidade_id = t2.id)
                                        INNER JOIN tipo_local t3 ON (t1.tipo_local_id = t3.id)
                                        WHERE (t1.cidade_id = ?) AND (status = 1) AND (t1.nome LIKE ? OR t3.tipo LIKE ?)
                                        ORDER BY t1.nome");
        $stm->bindParam(1, $idCidade);
        $stm->bindParam(2, $find);
        $stm->bindParam(3, $find);
        $stm->execute();
        $lista = $stm->fetchAll();

        return $lista;
    }
```